# Constructing a nearly 0 stochastic process or stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I'm trying to define a stochastic process $X_t$ with values on $\mathbb{R}$ which has the following properties, for the time interval $t \in [0,T]$:

- $X_t$ takes values in $[0,1]$
- $m(\{t \in [0,T] : X_t>0\})\leq \epsilon$, for some prescribed $\epsilon\geq 0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $X_t$ is adapted to some other Lévy process $Z_t$ which takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
  Most importantly I am looking for the following Stopping condition to hold:
- Let $\tau_1,...$ and $r_1,...$ be the hitting times corresponding to when $X_t>0$ and when $X_t$ first becomes $0$ again.  I want $r_i -\tau_i$ to be small, always but stochastic.

I am not sure how to rigorously construct such a process...  Could I just have a sequence of stopping times (this seems to make sense) but then how do I enforce the 2 and 4th conditions?

Comment: What do you mean with hitting time "corresponding to when $X_t >0$"? It's not clear to me what it actually is, and why it should be a stopping time.

Comment: The first time $X_t$ become greater than $0$.

Comment: But unless you have a jump at that time your process will still be zero. So, for example in a Brownian motion the stopping times you have defined are all zero P a.s. I guess. Is this actually something you want?

Comment: Hmmm... not exactly.. I want a positive probability of these happening...

Comment: The map $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ for fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ is not necessarily measurable, so your second condition needs to be formulated more carefully. In any case, is $\epsilon$ fixed or random? I.e. do you mean that there is $\epsilon>0$ such that the property holds almost surely, or there is almost surely an $\epsilon>0$ such that the property holds?